# Is my RTD sensor voltage divider equation correct?

Tags: c++, embedded

```
double Vs = 3.3;
double r1 = 10000.0;
double Vo = raw * .0001; //PSOC: .1mv to volt.
double r2 =  (r1 * Vo) / (Vs - Vo);

std::cout << "Raw rtd reading = " << raw << std::endl;
std::cout << "Voltage Output = " << Vo << std::endl;
std::cout << "voltage Source = " << Vs << std::endl;
std::cout << "Given Resistance = " << r1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Acquired Resistance = " << r2 << std::endl;

return -412.6 + (140.41 * pow(1 + (0.00764*r2), 0.5)) + (-6.25e-17 * (r2 * r2 * r2 *r2 *r2)) + (-1.25e-24 * (r2 * r2 * r2 * r2 * r2 * r2 *r2));
```

Is this correct? I keep on getting weird values returned to me. A lot of them being nan or 65,000 values.

Comment: What is an RTD sensor?  The "rtd" tag has no explanation.  Don't you just love acronynms?

Comment: You may want to consider using `sqrt` rather than `pow(x, 0.5)`.

Comment: we have no context to your code, no explanations what variable/constant is what so we can not help/advice ... +Close as unclear

Answer (score 0):

No, your equation is not correct if you're trying to compute the voltage division of some sensor that provides an analog voltage as its output.  Voltage division is common way to normalize voltages from such analog devices.  But  that last term for example

```
(-6.25e-17 * (r2 * r2 * r2 *r2 *r2)) + (-1.25e-24 * (r2 * r2 * r2 * r2 * r2 * r2 *r2)
```

does not appear be any voltage divider computation.  Any number of online resources will show the voltage divider equation to be:

[image]